# App on a Vagrant box running Laravel Homestead only displays 'It Works' upon fresh install of Laravel App

Tags: laravel, nginx, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I install a new Laravel app into my `/sites` folder called 'blog' using the `laravel new blog` terminal command.

The site builds fine, no errors on the terminal.

Then I used the `subl /etc/hosts` command to open up the hosts file in Sublime Text 3. Here is the contents of that file.

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1   laraveltest.app
127.0.0.1   makoto.app
127.0.0.1   modelawiki.app
127.0.0.1   fresher.app
127.0.0.1   blog.app
```

Right now let's focus on blog.app.

I then use the `subl Homestead.yaml` command to open and edit the Homestead.yaml file and update the maps. Here's the contents of that file.

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/www/sites
      to: /home/vagrant/sites

sites:
    - map: blog.app
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/blog/public
    - map: laraveltest.app
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/laravelTest/public
    - map: makoto.app
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/Makoto
    - map: modelawiki.app
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/modelawiki
    - map: fresher.app
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/fresher/public


databases:
    - homestead
```

I then run the `homestead provision` command which is an alias for `vagrant provision` to update everything and get the site up and running.

Now before running the `vagrant provision` command, every other site (laraveltest.app:8000, makoto.app:8000, etc.) worked just fine, and or displayed the Default Laravel Splash screen (laraveltest.app:8000).

When visiting any of the sites mapped in the homestead.yaml file, all I'm getting is the following page displayed...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KckKr.jpg

Here's the HTML output.

`<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>`

I'm confused on what I did wrong. I'm a newer user going through the Laravel Tutorials on LaraCasts. I followed CodeCourses videos on YouTube to help me install the Vagrant Box onto my machine.

I've also tried to see what was out there on the net for this issue and all i could find is this article on laravel valet... but it seems as though this isn't the tutorial I need.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/valet-v112-update-just-keep-getting-the-it-works

Edit: I'm currently in the process of uninstalling the vagrant box running laravel/homestead. I did the `vagrant destroy <id>` command and the `vargrant box remove`. I then edited the `/etc/hosts` file and removed all the edited custom app names. I then also deleted my Homestead folder containing my `homestead.yaml` file. I'm hopefully starting with a fresh install here soon.

Comment: Your edit message suggests this problem is solved. Would you add a self-answer below to present your solution? (If your _Edit 2_ is the solution, please move it to an answer, so as to preserve the Q&A format - thanks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the OP)*.

I reinstalled everything including the Vagrant box, and Homestead. Everything runs as normal. Don't know what happened. However the only way I can connect to my sites are to actually type the port in the URL. i.e. `blog.app:8000`. If i visit `blog.app` by itself, then the "It Works!" header comes back up and the laravel site goes away.

I'm thinking this might be an issue with nginx, and port forwarding? Since this is the case and the original question has been answered by myself, I'll be asking a new question about port forwarding and Laravel homestead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your sites-available ? try this line inside the virtual machine (after command `vagrant ssh`):

```
serve blog.app ~/sites/blog/public
```

Comment: Does not work. I'm sorry. This is the output and whats showing after running the command. http://imgur.com/a/C9zvu

Comment: What do you see in this directory? cd /etc/nginx/sites-available/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have already solved the problem, as you made an edit to your original question and linked to a new question. However, one thing I noticed that may have been causing your problem is the IP in your `/etc/hosts` file is does not match the IP in your `Homestead.yaml` file. When I use Laravel Homestead, I make sure that my `/etc/hosts` and `Homestead.yaml` files have identical IPs. I always get the Laravel splash page when I do this. Hopefully this is useful for future Vagrant boxes.